# VB8 How to have a listbox1 and listbox2 link together to populate a label?

Tags: hyperlink, linked-list, listbox

So i have search for this solution but cannot find what i need.

SO in vb8 i have 2 listbox. Listbox1 contains items of text nature. Whereas Listbox2 contains items of number nature.

1. Listbox1 contains text:

   - Dog  index = 0
   - Cat  index = 1
   - Bird index = 2
   - Fish index = 3
2. Listbox2 contains numbers:

   - 12  index = 0
   - 14  index = 1
   - 78  index = 2
   - 94  index = 3

So i want to select a item in Listbox1 and have it automatically input the corresponding number ( by index of listbox2) into a label.

ie. when dog is selected it has a selectedindex of 0. i am trying to get it so that in the label1 it would be the selectedindex of 0 of listbox2 which is = 12

I have been trying to manipulate a lot of different codes that i found on the internet, but nothing will work.

Thank you for any help that can be provided.

I have found this code on google and have been trying to manipulate it but still does not work.

```
           ' Get the currently selected item in the ListBox.
    Dim curItem As String = ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString()

    ' Find the string in ListBox2.
    Dim index1 As Integer = ListBox2.FindString(curItem)
    ' If the item was not found in ListBox 2 display a message box, otherwise select it in ListBox2.
    If index1 = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Item is not available in ListBox2")
    Else
        ListBox2.SetSelected(index1, True)
    End If
```

Comment: add your current code and SO will help you make it work.

Comment: the problem is i dont really know where to start with this one, i am very new to vb.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't Google. Google is Google.

Comment: i have been using google for 5 hours straight.

Comment: also i have found this code on "google" and i have been tring to manipulate it to work for me.

           ' Get the currently selected item in the ListBox.
        Dim curItem As String = ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString()

        ' Find the string in ListBox2.
        Dim index1 As Integer = ListBox2.FindString(curItem)
        ' If the item was not found in ListBox 2 display a message box, otherwise select it in ListBox2.
        If index1 = -1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Item is not available in ListBox2")
        Else
            ListBox2.SetSelected(index1, True)
        End If

Answer (score 0):

LMAO so i have figured out how to answer my own question by accident.

```
    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged





    ListBox2.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.SelectedIndex




End Sub
```

well thank you everyone.

then to input the numbers into a label:

```
    Private Sub ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    Label1.Text = ListBox2.Text

End Sub
```